# Glass Render- Gray Lines

Tags: glass

I just followed the famous donut and coffee cup guide online (for beginners ofc) and I am facing a problem which I am not sure how to solve (or what exactly I did wrong .. that's a possibility).
I modeled a glass + applied materials to it and set it to be transparent ( i attached in the pictures the settings for the materials). Even so, when i render the object it appears with some gray lines over there which I am not sure how to fix.  You can see those gray lines (I am pointing them in the picture), which I am not sure why they are there, and how to fix them.
Any solutions (please explain it simply as I am still having a hard time getting all the elements)

[image]

Comment: Those grey lines are a result of the glass refracting the scene environment - namely the grey "skies." Anything that changes the surrounding would fix that issue. Adding objects to the environment, adjusting the scene environment or using HDRIs as a few examples

Comment: or it might be flipped normals, select your object, go in Edit mode and alt N > Recalculate Outside

Comment: Thank you very much. !